# How can I connect or integrate flutter application with Oracle database or APEX?

Tags: flutter, oracle

We are developing an attendance management system for a University, where teachers can take student attendance using their phone. The university already has an Oracle database with student attendance and marks etc. Now the question is how can I manage to update those attendance fields from flutter application. I read about APEX, but it seems like APEX is an app development framework.

Can I integrate both?

Are there any Oracle API's?

How can I make my own Oracle API?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: we have the front end completed but i want to connect ti to the oracle database and i don't know how to connect them together. and i want to use just the student attendance from the whole database.

Answer (score 0):

From Flutter you can leverage ORDS in your Oracle database. ORDS = Oracle Rest Data Services.

Once ORDS is enabled on your tables you can access database directly through this and also create packages of endpoints to perform various tasks.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-rest-data-services/23.2/index.html